# My own game disappears after installation on Google play store

Tags: android

[image]I have a problem where I just installed my own game I made into my phone, but however my game just appears to be not be openable it just shows one button "Uninstall", instead of open. I do however saw that my app appears to be hidden in my phone app settings. Did I did something wrong? I used Android studio to make my signed APK or AAB game. For this published game it is a AAB. Is that bad?[image]

Comment: In order for an app to be launchable, you need to define a default activity, and tag is as a launchable one. This will put a "shortcut" on your phone, so you can launch the app from the home screen. Can you share the `AndroidManifest.xml` file? Make sure to remove any personal information (if any) on it. I'm not sure if that's why the play store doesn't offer the "Open" button, but it might be one of the reasons.

Comment: Yeah sure give me time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the screenshot you've posted of your Manifest, it looks like you don't have any activities on your project. Activities are individual "screens" that can be launched to display content on the screen, on Android.

To add an Activity on Android Studio, you can navigate to `File` -> `New` -> `Activity`. The UI will guide you through the process. This will also update your Manifest automatically, so outside programs (including the Play Store) will know how to launch your app.

Apart from that, you also need a Default Activity. In an app that includes many Activities, this will determine which one should open when a user launches your app. The usual syntax in the Manifest looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyAppActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.activity.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What Activities are and how to take fully advantage of them is a very big discussion, that can't fit into one answer here. To read more about it you can read more on [Android Developers - Introduction to Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities).